# why isn't my post showing up?

Tags: support, search

[Have there been instances of rivalry between Brahmins and Kshatriyas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26393/have-there-been-instances-of-rivalry-between-brahmins-and-kshatriyas)

If I search for it I can see it - but it doesn't show up in the list of posts.

Comment: What do you mean by "list of posts"?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is there now - but my fan club has garnered 4 "close" votes.

Comment: There is no your fan club. Everyone likes you personally. But Only  disagree with the way.

Comment: Which lists of posts actually? May be so because it was heavily downvoted..

Comment: @Rickross The OP is talking about the linked one. All the questions and answers along with deleted ones are visible to the OP. This question is posted without minimum research effort. Just looking into their profile would have been enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your posts are visible in [your profile](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/current) under tabs questions and answers. You can also search for your posts using a search operator `user:userID`. Every user has their own user ID. for you it is `12489` So, search for [user:12489](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12489+). For more see [How do I search](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/searching).